# How can i bind editFuction in extjs to actioncolumn?

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I have this actioncolumn in my user.List view:

```
    xtype: "actioncolumn",
            items: [
                {
                    tooltip: "Edit",
                    icon:'resources/img/edit.png',
                    handler: function (grid, rowIndex) {
                        var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
 //                            alert("Edit " + rec.get('username'));
                    }
                }
    ]
```

And in my controller i have this:

```
 init: function() {
    this.control({
        'userlist': {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser
        },
        'useredit button[action=save]': {
            click: this.updateUser
        }
    });
},

editUser: function(grid, record) {
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');

    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},
```

i want somehow to link the Edit from actioncolumn to my editUser function in controller somehow , i`m stuck and i could use some help :)

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using? 4 or 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ExtJS4:

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    ...

    me.columns = [
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            tooltip: 'Edit',
            icon:'resources/img/edit.png',
            handler: Ext.bind(me.editUser, me)
        }
    ]

    me.callParent(arguments);
    ...
}
```